# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar que un párrafo (p) en HTML se ponga color rojo al pulsar sobre un enlace utilizando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Este es el contenido del body en mi HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link five</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p id="paralink1">Looks like you clicked the first link in the list</p>
<p id="paralink2">Looks like you clicked the second link in the list</p>
<p id="paralink3">Looks like you clicked the third link in the list</p>
<p id="paralink4">Looks like you clicked the fourth link in the list</p>
<p id="paralink5">Looks like you clicked the fifth link in the list</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $("nav ul li a").click(function() {

        // Construye #paralink3 por ejemplo
        const paraNumber = "#para" + $(this).attr("id");

        $("p").css("color", "black");
        $(paraNumber).css("color", "red");
    });

</script>
```

***Estoy utilizando código en jQuery***

Lo que espero de la función hecha en jQuery es que cuando el usuario pulse sobre un link el párrafo correspondiente se coloree de rojo, por ejemplo al pulsar link one, el primer párrafo se ponga de color rojo y los demás continúen de color negro. Si el usuario pulsa el link five, el párrafo que tendrá que estar en color rojo es el párrafo cinco y los demás continúen negro, así al pulsar con los demás links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leyendo el código, en esta línea:

```
const paraNumber = "#para" + $(this).attr("id");
```

Utilizas el atributo `id`, que concatenas al valor `'#para'` y aquí:

```
$(paraNumber).css("color", "red");
```

Se ve que quieres tener en esta variable `paraNumber` el id del párrafo correspondiente. Los id's de los párrafos son `paralink1`, `paralink2`, etc.

De esto se deduce que a tus links les está faltando el atributo `id` para lograr que esta concatenación devuelva cada uno de los id's de los párrafos, es decir, `link1`, `link2`, etc.

En código, sería algo como:

```js
$("nav ul li a").click(function() {
    // Construye #paralink3 por ejemplo
    const paraNumber = "#para" + $(this).attr("id");
    $("p").css("color", "black");
    $(paraNumber).css("color", "red");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="link1">link one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="link2">link two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="link3">link three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="link4">link four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="link5">link five</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<p id="paralink1">Looks like you clicked the first link in the list</p>
<p id="paralink2">Looks like you clicked the second link in the list</p>
<p id="paralink3">Looks like you clicked the third link in the list</p>
<p id="paralink4">Looks like you clicked the fourth link in the list</p>
<p id="paralink5">Looks like you clicked the fifth link in the list</p>
```